# ImportError: No module named textract

Tags: python, package, importerror

I have installed textract using pip install and ran the import command in jupyter notebook which is throwing the following error.

I am on a windows machine and have two versions of python installed(2.7 and 3.6) using conda. I have also added the paths to environment variables as suggested in other posts but still getting the error.

```
import textract

ImportErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-99b3b0e1733d> in <module>()
     1 #Code to extract pdf files
----> 2 import textract
    3 text = textract.process("C:/Users/username/Documents/Projects/Attachments/PDF/fileA.pdf")

ImportError: No module named textract
```

EDIT:

I was only successful in installing textract on python 2.7. 
I have added the below paths to the environment variables
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\mypy27\
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\mypy27\Scripts---> this is where textract file is located
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\mypy27\Lib\lib-tk
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\mypy27\Lib
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\mypy27\DLLs

UPDATE:
I installed pypdf2 using pip install and tried importing it in juptyer notebooks.  It returned the same error. I was wondering if I am installing things incorrectly.

Comment: try to check in both versions of python and let us know if you are able to import in atleast one of them

Comment: tried both the versions. no luck

Comment: Try typing `pip --version` and `python -m pip --version`

Comment: May I know why? Btw,it returned 10.0.1 when I ran both the commands

Comment: @pysparker It might happen that while you may have installed the package for one python version and running the other one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a workaround.

1.Uninstalled Anaconda and re-installed it.

2.Did not create any python 2.7 environment in anaconda and  re-installed textract using pip along with all the other dependencies in the base anaconda command prompt.

3.Tried importing textract and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on ubuntu

1.Open terminal

```
python -m venv env 
source ./env/bin/activate
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python-pip && pip install --upgrade pip
sudo apt install python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev antiword unrtf poppler-utils pstotext tesseract-ocr flac ffmpeg lame libmad0 libsox-fmt-mp3 sox libjpeg-dev swig
pip install textract
```

if you face any more errors:

try

```
pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/ce/c7/ab6cd0d00ddf8dc3b537cfb922f3f049f8018f38c88d71fd164f3acb8416/SpeechRecognition-3.6.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
sudo apt install libpulse-dev
pip install textract
```

Now you will be able to import textract

```
import textract
text = textract.process("/home/user/textract_test.pdf")
```