# jupyterlab not detecting installed module: textract and doc2text

Tags: python, pip, conda, jupyter-lab, development-environment

I did this in a jupyter lab cell:

```
!pip install textract
```

and i managed to installed it successfully.

I also installed textract and doc2text in command line too in my conda environment.

But when I tried to import in a jupyter lab cell:

```
import textract
```

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[25], line 1
----> 1 import textract

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'textract'
```

I understand there is already some questions on these so I tried the most upvoted answers out without any avail.
[ImportError: No module named textract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50953880/importerror-no-module-named-textract)
[Python textract ImportError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44295470/python-textract-importerror)

The funny part is that in python interpreter prompt on command line, I am able to import these.

Comment: You should be using current best practices for installing things. First if Anaconda/conda is your primary package manager because you chose you install that, you should always primarily use that to install things. In this case you'd search the package in the Anaconda/conda documentation and adapt that command to run in the notebook with the `%conda install magic`. For example, based on [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/textract), you'd run in a new cell in your notebook where you want to use it `%conda install -c conda-forge textract` and then restart the kernel and try the import. ...

Comment: That is fair, thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: <continued> Second, if there was no Anaconda/conda recipe for the package you want, then in your notebook you could run `%pip install <package_needed_name>. After it completes, restart the kernel and try the import statement. The magic install commands were added in 2019. and insure the install occurs in the environment where the kernel is running that backs the running notebook. The exclamation point used in conjunction with install commands can cause problems because it doesn't insure the correct location of installation. And the modern magic install commands are more convenient than the ...

Comment: <continued> complex version of the install command that you have added as an answer. See more about the magic install commands [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez). More at the top [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) about why using the exclamation point in conjunction with install commands run in a notebook can lead to problems. You can use that a gauge for more current advice for working with Jupyter.

Comment: I should have added that sticking with installing with Anaconda/conda leads to more robust and portable environments. Where as mixing and matching installation approaches is a recipe for fragile environments and headaches down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to bing chat/copilot it lead me to this answer:

[Jupyter Notebook: module not found even after pip install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61265125/jupyter-notebook-module-not-found-even-after-pip-install)

in my environment command line I run this code and it was display in jupyter lab kernel selection alert box.

```
ipython kernel install --name "<YOUR ENVIRONMENT HERE>" --user
```